# R map org headlines to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, org-mode

I have a simple `org` file as follows:

```
* Title
** Book 1
*** Chapter 1
*** Chapter 2
...
** Book 3
...
```

I would like to map the above headline structure to a dataframe so that each chapter can be related to its corresponding book and title as follows:

```
data.frame(title="Title", bk=c("Book 1", "Book 1", "Book 3"), ch=c("Chapter 1", "Chapter 2", "Chapter 1"))

  title     bk        ch
1 Title Book 1 Chapter 1
2 Title Book 1 Chapter 2
...
32 Title Book 3 Chapter 1
```

The depth of each headline can be indexed with this code:

```
headlines=grep('\\*', input, value=T)
id=str_count(headlines, "\\*")
```

So that the following would give me separate vectors for books and chapters (title is pretty straightforward, in this case):

```
ch=headlines[id==3]
bk=headlines[id==2]
```

As we can see, the `ch` vector would definitely be longer than the `bk`. Using `id` as a reference, how do we get `bk` to repeat correspondingly so that they can be bound together to form the dataframe above?

Other approaches are also welcome.

---

## The Actual Data

Following is the actual data, corresponding to books and chapters in the Analects. For those who cannot read Chinese, a single * is the title of the whole (collection of) book(s), ** is the individual books, *** is the chapters.

```
headlines=
c("* 論語", "** 學而第一", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", 
"*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", 
"*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", 
"*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", 
"*** 第16章", "** 為政第二", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", 
"*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", 
"*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", 
"*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", 
"*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", 
"*** 第20章", "*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", 
"*** 第24章", "** 八佾第三", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", 
"*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", 
"*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", 
"*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", 
"*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", 
"*** 第20章", "*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", 
"*** 第24章", "*** 第25章", "*** 第26章", "** 里仁第四", 
"*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", "*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", 
"*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", 
"*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", 
"*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", 
"*** 第19章", "*** 第20章", "*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", 
"*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", "*** 第25章", "*** 第26章", 
"** 公冶長第五", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", "*** 第3章", 
"*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", 
"*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", 
"*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", 
"*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", "*** 第20章", 
"*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", 
"*** 第25章", "*** 第26章", "*** 第27章", "*** 第28章", 
"** 雍也第六", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", "*** 第3章", 
"*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", 
"*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", 
"*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", 
"*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", "*** 第20章", 
"*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", 
"*** 第25章", "*** 第26章", "*** 第27章", "*** 第28章", 
"** 述而第七", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", "*** 第3章", 
"*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", 
"*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", 
"*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", 
"*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", "*** 第20章", 
"*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", 
"*** 第26章", "*** 第27章", "*** 第28章", "*** 第29章", 
"*** 第30章", "*** 第31章", "*** 第32章", "*** 第33章", 
"*** 第34章", "*** 第35章", "*** 第36章", "*** 第37章", 
"*** 第38章", "** 泰伯第八", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", 
"*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", 
"*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", 
"*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", 
"*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", 
"*** 第20章", "*** 第21章", "** 子罕第九", "*** 第1章", 
"*** 第2章", "*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", 
"*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", 
"*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", 
"*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", 
"*** 第19章", "*** 第20章", "*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", 
"*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", "*** 第25章", "*** 第26章", 
"*** 第27章", "*** 第28章", "*** 第29章", "*** 第30章", 
"** 鄉黨第十", "*** 第1章", "*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", 
"*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", 
"*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", 
"*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", 
"*** 第18章", "** 先進第十一", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", 
"*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", 
"*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", 
"*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", 
"*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第19章", "*** 第21章", 
"*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", 
"** 顏淵第十二", "*** 第1章", "*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", 
"*** 第5章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", 
"*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", 
"*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", 
"*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", "*** 第20章", 
"*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", 
"** 子路第十三", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", "*** 第3章", 
"*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", 
"*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", 
"*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", 
"*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", "*** 第20章", 
"*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", 
"*** 第25章", "*** 第26章", "*** 第27章", "*** 第28章", 
"*** 第29章", "*** 第30章", "** 憲問第十四", "*** 第1章", 
"*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", 
"*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", 
"*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", 
"*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", 
"*** 第20章", "*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", 
"*** 第24章", "*** 第25章", "*** 第26章", "*** 第27章", 
"*** 第28章", "*** 第29章", "*** 第30章", "*** 第31章", 
"*** 第32章", "*** 第33章", "*** 第34章", "*** 第35章", 
"*** 第36章", "*** 第37章", "*** 第38章", "*** 第39章", 
"*** 第41章", "*** 第42章", "*** 第43章", "*** 第44章", 
"*** 第45章", "*** 第46章", "*** 第47章", "** 衛靈公第十五", 
"*** 第1章", "*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", 
"*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", 
"*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", 
"*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", 
"*** 第19章", "*** 第20章", "*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", 
"*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", "*** 第25章", "*** 第26章", 
"*** 第27章", "*** 第28章", "*** 第29章", "*** 第30章", 
"*** 第31章", "*** 第32章", "*** 第33章", "*** 第34章", 
"*** 第35章", "*** 第36章", "*** 第37章", "*** 第38章", 
"*** 第39章", "*** 第40章", "*** 第41章", "*** 第42章", 
"** 季氏第十六", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", "*** 第3章", 
"*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", 
"*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", 
"*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "** 陽貨第十七", "*** 第1章", 
"*** 第2章", "*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", 
"*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", 
"*** 第11章", "*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", 
"*** 第15章", "*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", 
"*** 第19章", "*** 第20章", "*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", 
"*** 第23章", "*** 第24章", "** 微子第十八", "*** 第1章", 
"*** 第2章", "*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", 
"*** 第7章", "*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", 
"*** 第11章", "** 子張第十九", "*** 第1章", "*** 第2章", 
"*** 第3章", "*** 第4章", "*** 第5章", "*** 第6章", "*** 第7章", 
"*** 第8章", "*** 第9章", "*** 第10章", "*** 第11章", 
"*** 第12章", "*** 第13章", "*** 第14章", "*** 第15章", 
"*** 第16章", "*** 第17章", "*** 第18章", "*** 第19章", 
"*** 第20章", "*** 第21章", "*** 第22章", "*** 第23章", 
"*** 第24章", "*** 第25章", "** 堯曰第二十", "*** 第1章", 
"*** 第2章", "*** 第3章")
```

So I am looking for something like this:

```
   title          bk        ch
1 * 論語 ** 學而第一 *** 第1章
2 * 論語 ** 學而第一 *** 第2章
...
41 * 論語 ** 八佾第三 *** 第1章
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several methods are possible. One method:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
headlines <- c("Book 1", "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2", "Book 2", "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2")
id        <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2)

df <- data.frame(ID=id, Book=headlines, Chapter=headlines)
df %>% mutate(Book=ifelse(id == 1, Book, NA)) %>% fill(Book) %>% filter(id == 2)
```

Without using tidyverse:

```
books <- headlines[ id == 1 ]
chapters <- headlines[ id == 2 ]
rl <- rle(id)
reps <- rl$lengths[ rl$values == 2 ]
books <- unlist(lapply(1:length(books), function(i) rep(books[i], reps[i])))
df <- data.frame(Books=books, Chapters=chapters)
```

Comment: `str_count(headlines, "\\*")` includes the title, so corresponding values for books and chapters would be 2 and 3 respectively, rather than 1 and 2. I would probably use the same code to include content further down the tree structure, such as individual paragraphs, for example. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Sure, you need to adapt it to your needs. Next levels can be achieved in a similar way, but you'd need to give me a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you  have problems implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R method assuming your chapters would be in increasing fashion for each `book`

```
data.frame(title="Title", 
    bk = bk[cumsum(c(1, diff(as.integer(sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", ch))) < 0))], 
    ch = ch)

#  title        bk            ch
#1 Title ** Book 1 *** Chapter 1
#2 Title ** Book 1 *** Chapter 2
#3 Title ** Book 1 *** Chapter 3
#4 Title ** Book 3 *** Chapter 1
#5 Title ** Book 3 *** Chapter 2
```

As `title` and `ch` are already extracted and are in required length we do not change that. For `bk` let us understand it step-by-step

We first extract the numeric part of `ch` and convert it into an integer

```
as.integer(sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", ch))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2
```

then create an index which increments every time the numeric part decreases from its previous value

```
cumsum(c(1, diff(as.integer(sub(".*(?\\d+).*", "\\1", ch))) < 0))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2
```

Use this index to repeat values of `bk`

```
bk[cumsum(c(1, diff(as.integer(sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", ch))) < 0))]
#[1] "** Book 1" "** Book 1" "** Book 1" "** Book 3" "** Book 3"
```

**data**

```
ch <- c("*** Chapter 1", "*** Chapter 2", "*** Chapter 3", "*** Chapter 1", 
"*** Chapter 2")
bk  <- c("** Book 1", "** Book 3")
```

**EDIT**

It looks like it works with updated as well

```
data.frame(title="Title", 
        bk = bk[cumsum(c(1, diff(as.integer(sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", ch))) < 0))], 
        ch = ch)


#    title         bk         ch
#1   Title   ** 學而第一  *** 第1章
#2   Title   ** 學而第一  *** 第2章
#3   Title   ** 學而第一  *** 第3章
#4   Title   ** 學而第一  *** 第4章
#5   Title   ** 學而第一  *** 第5章
#6   Title   ** 學而第一  *** 第6章
#7   Title   ** 學而第一  *** 第7章
#8   Title   ** 學而第一  *** 第8章
#9   Title   ** 學而第一  *** 第9章
#10  Title   ** 學而第一 *** 第10章
#....
```

Comment: What if the books and chapters are not numbered?

Comment: @Sati if they are not numbered another option could be to remove  "Title" from `headlines` and create a similar incremental count using `cumsum` based on occurrence of word "Book".

Comment: Please take a look at the actual data that's been newly updated. Thank you!

Comment: @Sati I think it needed a small change in regex since you also have two digit chapters. Can you check the answer now?

Answer (score 0):

@January's second solution above works with the actual data, simply by changing some of the id values.

```
books <- headlines[ id == 2 ]
chapters <- headlines[ id == 3 ]
rl <- rle(id)
reps <- rl$lengths[ rl$values == 3 ]
books <- unlist(lapply(1:length(books), function(i) rep(books[i], reps[i])))
df <- data.frame(Books=books, Chapters=chapters)
```